# Increase the timeout limit for LDAP in C#

Tags: c#, timeout, ldap

I hit the LDAP of organization to get user's details (ID, email) by giving the user's name as an input. The query I use times out. Is there a way to increase the timeout limit?

Comment: Are you sure that the LDAP server is up and running? The timeout is there for a reason.

Comment: Yeah. It returns values for some names and doesn't for some. Also it gives timeout for the same name for which it fetched values some time back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase your [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.timeout.aspx)?

Comment: The connection will close if it finishes fetching values before the timeout right?

Comment: Yes, the timeout is just to force the connection to close after a duration of time.  This is not how long to wait for the connection to be established (which you aren't having issues with).

Comment: Thanks Erik. I have another question. I am invoking LDAP in C# by using the System.DirectoryServices. Now for some reason the Maximum Timeput Exception is thrown even on forcing the timeout. Is there a way I can check if the LDAP Connection, or the LDAP Connection is up? Something like ping which I can use to ping the Sever, from the command prompt.

Comment: Creating a LDAPConnection does not create a network connection. The `BeginSendRequest` and `SendRequest` create network connections. I would assume the connections are automatically handled internally by the LDAPConnection class.

Comment: Hey Erik, I use the following :

Comment: I use the following code snippet for the connection. It gives me a timeout error. LdapDirectoryIdentifier ldapId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(configData.LDAPServer);
                    ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldapId, new NetworkCredential(configData.LDAPUserId, configData.LDAPPassword), AuthType.Basic);
                    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
                    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                    ldapConnection.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 30);
                    ldapConnection.Bind();

Comment: Is there a way to check if the LDAP Server is currently running @ the Server location or no?